# r ggplot geom point add border with different color and shape

Tags: r, ggplot2, geom-point

I have the following initial situation:
I have made the colour and shape of the points in a scatter plot dependent on the same variable. But because the points overlap, you can't see the individual data points very well, so I need a line.

My problem:
I can't manage to give the different shapes an outer line in black without the colour of the whole point/traingle changing completely.

Here is my code, does anyone have any ideas?

```
ggplot(mydata, aes_string(x = "metric_var1", y = "metric_var2", shape = "categ_var"))+
  geom_point(aes(colour = categ_var), size = 3)+
  scale_colour_manual(values=c("#13678A", "#FFD579"))
```

Thanks already!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a [shape](https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/articles/ggplot2-specs.html#sec:shape-spec) for `geom_point()` that has a border, i.e. shapes 21-24.
The border is controled by the aesthetics `color` and `stroke`, the inside by `fill` and `size`.

```r
ggplot(mydata, aes_string(x = "metric_var1", y = "metric_var2", shape = "categ_var")) +
  geom_point(aes(fill = categ_var), color = "black", size = 3) +
  scale_fill_manual(values=c("#13678A", "#FFD579")) + 
  scale_shape_manual(values=21:22)
```